# Keeping Timer in JPanel alive while program is running

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, jpanel

I have a GUI created in a class called MainFrame. One of the JPanels of the GUI displays the current time and date, by second. When the user decides to use the GUI to analyze data, it invokes a class that processes data. When the data process is happening, the timer pauses, then resumes when the dataprocess is over. How can I have the timer continuously run even if the program is running? The timer is its own thread, but I do not understand where to start a thread for a JPanel.
Here are some code cut-outs

App.java (app to start the entire GUI)

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MainFrame (class that handles the JPanels and dataprocess impl)

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private DataProcess dataProcess = null;
...
...
    private StatusPanel statusPanel;
...
...
public MainFrame() {
...
        setJMenuBar(createFrameMenu());

        initializeVariables();
        constructLayout();
        createFileChooser();
        constructAppWindow();
}

    private void initializeVariables() {

        this.dataProcess = new DataProcess();
...
        this.statusPanel = new StatusPanel();
...
}
    private void constructLayout() {
        JPanel layoutPanel = new JPanel();
        layoutPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        layoutPanel.add(dataControlsPanel());

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(layoutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }
```

StatusPanel (panel that shows timer etc)

```
public class StatusPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JLabel timeLabel;

    private Timer timer;

    public StatusPanel() {
        initializeVariables();
        constructLayout();
        startTimer();
    }

    private void constructLayout() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(statusLabel);// , FlowLayout.CENTER
        add(timeLabel);
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        this.timer.start();
    }

    public void stopTimer() {
        this.timer.setRunning(false);
    }

    private void initializeVariables() {
        this.statusLabel = new JLabel();
        this.timeLabel = new JLabel();
        this.statusLabel.setText(StringConstants.STATUS_PANEL_TEXT);
        this.timer = new Timer(timeLabel);
    }

}
```

Timer.java (timer that is used in StatusPanel)

```
public class Timer extends Thread {

    private boolean isRunning;
    private JLabel timeLabel;
    private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat;

    public Timer(JLabel timeLabel) {
        initializeVariables(timeLabel);
    }

    private void initializeVariables(JLabel timeLabel) {
        this.timeLabel = timeLabel;
        this.timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss  dd-MM-yyyy");
        this.isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date currentTime = calendar.getTime();
            timeLabel.setText(timeFormat.format(currentTime));

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
    }

}
```

Data process is done in the dataControlsPanel by use of actionlisteners.

Comment: Use a Swing Timer -- this situation is exactly what it's supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the user decides to use the GUI to analyze data, it invokes a class that processes data. When the data process is happening, the timer pauses, then resumes when the dataprocess is over. How can I have the timer continuously run even if the program is running

First of all, your timer should be a `javax.swing.Timer` or "Swing" Timer. This is built to work specifically on the Swing event thread and so should avoid many of the Swing threading problems that your current code shows -- for example, here: `timeLabel.setText(timeFormat.format(currentTime));` -- this makes a Swing call from a background thread and is dangerous code. Next 
The processing code should go into a SwingWorker. When the worker executes, you can pause the Swing Timer by calling `stop()` on the Timer, or simply let the timer to continue to run. When the SwingWorker has completed its action -- something I usually listen for with a PropertyChangeListener added to the SwingWorker, listening for its `state` property to change to `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE`, call `get()` on the worker to extract any data it holds and more importantly to capture any exceptions that might be thrown.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyApp extends JPanel {
    // display the date/time
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss  dd-MM-yyyy";
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    // timer updates measures seconds, but updates every 0.2 sec's to be sure
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 200;

    // JLabel that shows the date/time
    private JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // JButton's Action / listener. This starts long-running data processing
    private Action dataProcessAction = new DataProcessAction("Process Data");

    // the SwingWorker that the above Action executes:
    private LongRunningSwProcess longRunningProcess;

    // label to display the count coming from the process above
    private JLabel countLabel = new JLabel("00");

    public MyApp() {
        // create a simple GUI
        JPanel dataProcessingPanel = new JPanel();
        dataProcessingPanel.add(new JButton(dataProcessAction)); // button that starts process
        dataProcessingPanel.add(new JLabel("Count:"));
        dataProcessingPanel.add(countLabel);        

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(dataProcessingPanel);
        showTimeLabelCurrentTime();
        // create and start Swing Timer
        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start(); 
    }

    // display count from swing worker
    public void setCount(int newValue) {
        countLabel.setText(String.format("%02d", newValue));
    }

    // clean up code after SwingWorker finishes
    public void longRunningProcessDone() {
        // re-enable JButton's action
        dataProcessAction.setEnabled(true);
        if (longRunningProcess != null) {
            try {
                // handle any exceptions that might get thrown from the SW
                longRunningProcess.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // display the current time in our timeLabel JLabel
    private void showTimeLabelCurrentTime() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date date = new Date(currentTime);
        timeLabel.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    // Timer's ActionListener is simple -- display the current time in the timeLabel
    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            showTimeLabelCurrentTime();
        }
    }

    // JButton's action. This starts the long-running SwingWorker
    private class DataProcessAction extends AbstractAction {

        public DataProcessAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setEnabled(false); // first disable the button's action
            countLabel.setText("00"); // reset count label

            // then create SwingWorker and listen to its changes
            longRunningProcess = new LongRunningSwProcess();
            longRunningProcess.addPropertyChangeListener(new DataProcessListener());

            // execute the swingworker
            longRunningProcess.execute();
        }
    }

    // listen for state changes in our SwingWorker
    private class DataProcessListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(LongRunningSwProcess.COUNT)) {
                setCount((int)evt.getNewValue());
            } else if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                longRunningProcessDone();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyApp());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
// mock up of SwingWorker for long-running action
class LongRunningSwProcess extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {
    public static final String COUNT = "count";
    private static final int MIN_TIME_OUT = 5;
    private static final int MAX_TIME_OUT = 10;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // all this mock up does is increment a count field 
        // every second until timeOut reached
        int timeOut = MIN_TIME_OUT + (int) (Math.random() * (MAX_TIME_OUT - MIN_TIME_OUT));
        for (int i = 0; i < timeOut; i++) {
            setCount(i);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // make count a "bounded" property -- one that will notify listeners if changed
    public void setCount(int count) {
        int oldValue = this.count;
        int newValue = count;
        this.count = newValue;
        firePropertyChange(COUNT, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a few questions about your answer. Why is it "dangerous code"? Why would I stop the timer when what I am trying to accomplish is to have the timer progress even when dataprocess is happening. If I have a long dataprocess, I do not want the timer to stop.

Comment: @mkunkel: you're making Swing mutational calls in a thread that is off the event dispatch thread. This can result in threading exceptions that occur intermittently, making the errors *very* hard to debug. You will want to read up on and understand Swing threading rules if you're going to be creating Swing code that uses threads. Please start here: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: @mkunkel: Sorry, I misunderstood your requirements. If you want the Timer to continue to run, then don't stop it, and it *will* continue running if you follow my other suggestions.

Comment: I read many SO about swingworker and I was hoping to avoid swingworker as I yet to understand it. I am guessing it is unavoidable.

Comment: @mkunkel: why avoid them? To what purpose would that serve when it is the best tool for the job?

Comment: Because I have yet to understand them or implement them. However I just started this GUI, so maybe soon.

Comment: @mkunkel: now's as good as any time to learn. Hang on, I'll show you what I mean....